# How to fix when I started up the Android Studio and Generate the Emulator, but there is 6 errors

Tags: android-emulator

6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).

6 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

1. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
2. Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
3. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
4. Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
5. Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).
6. Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

   :app is currently compiled against android-32.

   Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion of at least 33, for example 33.

   Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed on).

Answer (score 0):

Edit 3:  Just discovered a likely more safe and complete way to do this:

[Changing Sdk Version using Android Studio menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H62Al.jpg)

If using Mac, go to File -> Project Structure.

Under *Modules*, look for *app*, and then look for the tab labeled *Properties*.  The first option, called *Compile Sdk version*, is the error. You want to change the compile Sdk version from 32 to 33.

---

*Original Post:*

I do! Just figured it out myself. See image below for visual guidance exact locations in Android Studio.

[Partial Screenshot of what to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rurd.png)

In the directory, find Gradle Scripts, and in Gradle Scripts find "build.gradle (Module :app)".

Within that, change compileSdk from 32 to 33, and change targetSdk from 32 to 33.   Look through build.gradle for anything else that might need updating number-wise.
Then click Sync Now at the top of the code editor.

I ran into this problem right away on the default "Hello World" app, so if you find it early it may be more helpful. I don't know how difficult it is to fix when something more complex has been put in place. I hope I help at least a little!

From,
A brand new student learning Android.  :)